# VisualStudio 2012 update 4 c# endless loop / debugger hang

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, conditional-breakpoint

What are the reproducible known states, conditions, or requests that cause the VisualStudio Debugger to "spin endlessly" or hang?

(Reworded because original question below was put on hold - Please consider decision to place question on hold because it IS reproducible and it is not quite as simple as a "typo" which the debugger would have caught and refused to set breakpoint like it does with other conditions it knows it is unable to handle.)
Has anyone else observed VisualStudio "spinning endlessly" when trying to use the debugger with a conditional breakpoint?
I waited more than 5 minutes with one cpu core "pegged" for "something to happen in my app."  During this time visualstudio was using >75% of one cpu core with about 2 or 3% reported as being used by the app.  Pausing appeared to have no effect.

Strangely the app started running normally and brought up the login screen after I disabled the conditional breakpoint.  I was then able to re-enable the conditional breakpoint and continue using the debugger with the conditional breakpoint active.

Comment: This is not unusual.  Conditional breakpoints can be very expensive when they are set inside code that's in a tight loop.

Comment: So expensive that the app appears to refuse to start!!??!!  (I am well aware of conditional breakpoints being VERY EXPENSIVE but not to the extent that NOTHING HAPPENS other than "VisualStudio talking to itself..."

Comment: Did you set the conditional breakpoint inside a loop? How many times is it evaluated during startup? Can you post some sample code demonstrating your issue?

Comment: I was trying to evaluate part of an IInvocation in a dynamicproxy used for tracing/logging methodcalls in an app.  Apparently it was going on vacation on the first attempt to evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like VisualStudio 2012 update 4's debugger / ide does not warn or know that it is incapable of handling a conditional breakpoint evaluating a variable if that variable accepts the result of an assigment on the line where the breakpoint is placed.

For example:

```
public static class MyTest
{
    public static bool DoTesting = true;
}
```

Setting a conditional breakpoint on the line where DoTesting is set to true and using the condition
MyTest.DoTesting == true
will apparently confuse VisualStudio's debbuger so much that it will spin and never run the rest of your code.  Hitting the "pause" button does NOT stop at the conditional statement line as you would expect it to it just "greys out" the "pause" button.  I think they should REFUSE to create the conditional breakpoint or complain about it (as it does with other conditions it is unable to handle.)  Note this will occur regardless of if it is the initial assignment or a line that re-assigns the value of the result.